# Custom data loader for images and labels in pytorch. Difficulty with inputs in loss function

Tags: image, pytorch, dataloader

I was working on this https://www.kaggle.com/gti-upm/leapgestrecog data set lately. Its a hand gesture dataset and I was trying to make a classifier. Due to images available in different types of folder I made my on data loader. Here it is

```
class DatasetLoader(Dataset):

  def __init__(self,path):
    self.path_list = path
    self.labels = []
    self.to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
    self.resize = transforms.Resize((120,320))
    self.gray = transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels = 1)
    self._init_dataset()

 def _init_dataset(self):
    labels = set()
    for diro in os.listdir("/kaggle/input/leapgestrecog/leapGestRecog"):
      for d in os.listdir(os.path.join("/kaggle/input/leapgestrecog/leapGestRecog",diro)):
        if len(d.split('_'))>2:
          labels.add("_".join(d.split("_")[-2:]))
        else:
          labels.add(d.split("_")[-1])
    labels = list(labels) 
    ## help me on this line with some codes

  def __getitem__(self,idx): 
    if torch.is_tensor(idx): 
      idx = idx.tolist() 
    img_name = self.path_list[idx] 
    img = Image.open(img_name) 
    img = self.resize(img) 
    img = self.gray(img) 
    img = self.to_tensor(img) 
    if len(img_name.split('/')[-2].split('_')) > 2: 
      label = "_".join(img_name.split('/')[-2].split('_')[-2:]) 
    else: 
      label = img_name.split('/')[-2].split('_')[-1] 
    label = ## Here also 
    return img,label

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.path_list)
```

I have problem with label which I am getting from this dataset loader. As I have created a model which takes n batches of data with 10 classes so during loss calculation I need my labels to of size(n,10). I dont know what to do. Here is my network design:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,32,5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,64,3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64,64,3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*38*13,128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128,10)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = x.view(64,64*38*13)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))

        return F.log_softmax(self.fc2(x),dim = 1)
```

If y is label of an image. To train our network we feed loss function with y and output. But output we get is of size (64,10) , so I need help with the `label` in dataloader

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a bit of misunderstanding about the input dimensions to a multi-class loss function in PyTorch. The most commonly used loss function for classification problems is `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`, which expects raw logits of size `(n, c)` (e.g. `(64, 10)`) as input1, and target (ground truth label) of size `(n)` (e.g. `(10)`).

So instead of doing `return F.log_softmax(self.fc2(x),dim = 1)`, it would be more stable to directly do `return x` and use `CrossEntropyLoss`. There is no need to reshape your labels, you can directly calculate the loss by doing something like this:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
# Let x be (64, 10) output from model
# Let y be (10,) label
loss = criterion(x, y)
```